# What options are there to share emails aside from HiverHQ?

Tags: email, sharing

Rather than forward email threads or conversations to multiple people, the ideal solution would be the ability to share emails. [HiverHQ](http://hiverhq.com/) seems to have this capability. Are there options other than HiverHQ?

High level requirements (ideal)

- Share emails with multiple people
- Remove the ability to share emails
- Share emails with those using other providers e.g. Microsoft, Yahoo
- Collaborate on emails similar to documents